# How do I parse request data in Python-Django?

Tags: python, django

I am getting the django request.POST in the format :
{
    'a': 1,
    'b[c]': 2,
    'b[d]': 3,
    'b[e]': 4,
    'f[g]': 5,
    'f[h]': 6
}

How do i parse it so that I get a dict in the format:
{
    'a': 1,
    'b': {
        'c': 2,
        'd': 3,
        'e': 4
    },
    'f': {
        'g': 5,
        'h': 6
    }
}

Is there something out of the box in Django/Python which I am missing?
(Using Python 2.7, Django 1.8)

TIA

Comment: What did you already tried? please post your code

Comment: @wolendranh: Tried everything in simplejson library and normal requests library stuff. PHP has inbuilt support to read this kind of data. Trying to understand if Python also has something similar.

Comment: Rather than parse this, you should send it in the right format to start with. What is sending this data and why isn't it using either standard form-encoded data, or JSON?

Comment: how did you get this post data? was it json format?  If so, do you know about json.loads()?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I am getting this request from 3rd party, who are not willing to change it on their end, hence, I only have to do it.

jQuery sends the request data in the same format if traditional = False
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser)'s a project that claims to parse this data for Django; I've no idea whether it works.

Comment: @joelgoldstick: since request.POST is not a valid json, json.loads() is failing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thank you so much. It worked. Looking at the code, it seems as if it was tailor made specially for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to this:

```
d = { 'a': 1, 'b[c]': 2, 'b[d]': 3, 'b[e]': 4, 'f[g]': 5, 'f[h]': 6 }

def parse_post_dict(d):
    new_d = {}
    for key in d.iterkeys():
        if "[" in key and "]" in key:
            key_split = key.split("[")
            outer_key = key_split[0]
            inner_key = key_split[1].replace("]", "")

            if outer_key not in new_d:
                new_d[outer_key] = {}

            new_d[outer_key][inner_key] = d[key]
        else:
            new_d[key] = d[key]

    return new_d


print parse_post_dict(d)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I went with [this](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser) solution.